# Feeder for returning an array of items rated by users

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

`Feeder` is in charge of returning an array of items rated by users (`feed`). If there is a watching user (`current_user`), the `Rating`s should be from all users being `influencers` except for a watching user.

`Scroll` is given by [a gem](https://github.com/dblock/mongoid-scroll). It gives a cursor for each rating so that infinite scrolls will work.

I see this pattern quite frequently in my code: one `if` statement where very little changes. How can this be refactored?

```
class Feeder
def self.most_recent_created(watching_user=nil, current_cursor)

    next_cursor = nil
    feed = []
    influencers_ids = User.any_in(roles: ["influencer"]).distinct(:_id)

    if watching_user
        Rating.not_from(watching_user).but_from(influencers_ids).over_zero.desc(:created_at).limit(IMOS_PER_PAGE).scroll(current_cursor) do |rating, cursor|
          next_cursor = cursor
          imo = Imo.new(rating)
          imo_presenter = ImoPresenter.new(imo, watching_user)
          feed.push(imo_presenter)
        end
    else
      Rating.from(influencers_ids).over_zero.desc(:created_at).limit(IMOS_PER_PAGE).scroll(current_cursor) do |rating, cursor|
        next_cursor = cursor
        imo = Imo.new(rating)
        imo_presenter = ImoPresenter.new(imo)
        feed.push(imo_presenter)
      end

    end

    feed.push(next_cursor.to_s)

  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working on the assumption that `Rating` is an ActiveRecord subclass, and you're using scopes to compose a query. Scopes return a proxy object which you can further scope, and then you coalesce them into a query. I'm not familiar with `scroll` but I'm assuming that it is what does that in this case.

```
class Feeder
  def self.most_recent_created(watching_user = nil, current_cursor)
    influencers_ids = User.any_in(roles: ["influencer"]).distinct(:_id)
```

You can use a pattern like this to progressively build a query proxy based on some series of `if` conditions:

```
    proxy = Rating.from(influencers_ids).over_zero.desc(:created_at).limit(IMOS_PER_PAGE)
    proxy = proxy.not_from(watching_user) if watching_user
```

And then once you have your proxy built, you can just call your coalescing method on it and handle it as you normally would:

```
    feed = []
    next_cursor = nil
    proxy.scroll(current_cursor) do |rating, cursor|
      next_cursor = cursor
      feed << ImoPresenter.new(Imo.new(rating), watching_user)
    end

    feed.push(next_cursor.to_s)
  end
end
```

More generally, composable queries via scopes can be leveraged to dramatically reduce code duplication. Start with something like:

```
proxy = MyModel
```

And then start composing your scope based on some conditions:

```
proxy = proxy.some_scope(param) if condition?
proxy = proxy.another_scope if other_condition?
proxy = proxy.yet_another_scope unless third_condition?
```

And then finally process your query:

```
proxy.each {|record| ... }
```

If you find that you're duplicating parts of that composition, then you can condense them into a single scope. So if you find that you're always writing:

```
proxy = proxy.some_scope(param) if condition?
proxy = proxy.another_scope if other_condition?
```

Just condense it into a scope:

```
scope :compound_scope, ->(param) {
  proxy = self
  proxy = proxy.some_scope(param) if condition?
  proxy = proxy.another_scope if other_condition?
  proxy
}
```

Then you would use `compound_scope` in your controller code, avoiding code re-use.